# Is private key generation without prior communication possible in naive RSA?

Tags: encryption, rsa

From what I have understood of naive RSA (without padding) so far, it seems that A and B must first decide on the prime factors in order for B to generate its private key to decrypt A's message.
I do understand that the RSA system helps in the establishment of a secure "channel", rather than having to rely on creating a new secure channel everytime between A and B, but isn't this a circular argument?

If B is to generate its private key, A must first share a one time pad (or its equivalent) with B, and only then can it send the primes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**TL;DR:** *The secure communication channels set up by RSA are one way and not duplex between two users. A sets up a channel for anyone to use to send secure messages to A. B sets up a channel (independently, with different primes B chooses) for anyone to use to securely communicate to B.*

Not at all. The two parties independently choose their primes.

A chooses two random large primes $p,q$ computes the product $n=pq.$ A then chooses an encryption exponent $e$ and *since it knows* $p,q$ can efficiently determine the decryption exponent $d.$

(Note: It could also choose a decryption exponent $d$ and compute $e$, mathematically it's equivalent.

A publishes its public key $(n,e).$ This establishes a secure channel for *anyone* to send messages to A.

Independently, B chooses two random large primes $p',q'$ computes the product $n'=p'q'.$ B then chooses an encryption exponent $e'$ and *since it knows* $p',q'$ it can efficiently determine the decryption exponent $d'.$

B publishes its public key $(n',e').$ This establishes a secure channel for *anyone* to send messages to B.

Comment: In that case, how could B possibly decrypt A's message, if all it has access to is pq and e?

Comment: Nevermind. (Leaving this up in case anyone else has this misconception as well.)